# How does the Django setting of letting it know about your app really work?

Tags: python, django

I've been learning django for a few weeks , but i still cant fully understand how some of the settings really work,like the most basic one that when i create a new app called 'base' inside my django project then i should let django know about my app so i write like as most of the people do

```
'INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',

  'base.apps.BaseConfig',
```

]'

but if i  write just only my app name 'base' , it still works , so can someone tell me what is the difference between this two?

```
'INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',

  'base',
```

]'

Answer (score 0):

There is no that much difference.

It's better to create CustomAppConfig, Because you can tune different parameters like name, label, a verbose_name for admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can consider `base` as shortname of your application and `base.apps.BaseConfig` as its longname. If you are working on a simple project you can go on with `base`, but if you want to have specific configurations for an application you should use `base.apps.BaseConfig`.

According to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) you'd better to define a subclass of AppConfig in your app's `apps.py` and use the dotted path (longname) `base.apps.BaseConfig`  in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

See the [Configurable Attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#configurable-attributes) of AppConfig class for details.